# Can't create automation with steps with SOAP API/WS Proxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm struggling to create a Automation with Steps via SSJS WS Proxy. I was however, successful to create one without any step. I provided all required IDs from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm) but I get very generic error message `Failed to create Program`. Is this even possible in one step? Or maybe I need to create empty automation first and then update the steps in separated transaction? I saw that there are undocumented REST endpoints that allow me to do it as well, but I need to do with SOAP/WS Proxy. My code example below:

```
Platform.Load('Core', '1.1.5');
var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

proxy.setClientId({ID: '1234'});

var automationDefinition = {};
automationDefinition.Name = 'MyName';
automationDefinition.CustomerKey = 'MyKey';
automationDefinition.AutomationType = 'scheduled';
automationDefinition.AutomationTasks = [
    {
        Name: '1st step',
        Activities: [
            { 
                ActivityObject : {
                    CustomerKey: 'QueryCustomerKey',
                    ObjectID : 'QueryObjectID'
                }, 
                Name: 'QueryName',
                ObjectID : 'QueryObjectID'
            }
        ]
    }
];

var response = proxy.createItem('Automation', automationDefinition);
```